# Linking a pop-up prompt to the next dataset of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, hyperlink, popup

I have created a multi-dimensional array that I am using to make a quiz. However, I need each question (array) to have a set time limit. I was able to create a simple prompt stating "You've ran out of time". Is there any way I could get the 'ok' button in the prompt pop-up to be linked to the next question (the next dataset/array that I have set up in the code). Right now I have it linked to just a random website. I am not sure if it has anything to do with autosubmit or even what to do at this point. Please help me out here guys. Thanks!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <title>Random Quiz</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:10px 40px 40px 40px; }
</style>
<script>

  function myFunction() {
    alert('Oops! Looks like you ran out of time.');
window.location = 'http://www.webkinz.com/';
}

var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "Who is the current President?", "Clinton", "Obama", "Dixon", "Washinton", "B" ],
    [ "What is the first letter of the Alphabet?", "the letter a", "the letter b", "the letter c", "the letter d", "A" ],
    [ "What is my middle name?", "Jack", "Ray", "Billy", "Earl", "D" ],
    [ "What class is this?", "Math", "Science", "Web Design", "English", "C" ],
  [ "Fill in the blank: Red ____ Cup", "Bird", "Solo", "Tear", "Juice", "B" ],
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    chD = questions[pos][4];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> "+chD+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][5]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);">
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not very experienced so please be as specific and complete as possible